# Fluent nHibernate - How to map a non-key column on a junction table?

Tags: c#, database, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

Taking an example that is provided on the Fluent nHibernate website, I need to extend it slightly:

[image]
<sub>(source: [fluentnhibernate.org](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/images/2/24/FirstProjectSchema.png))</sub>

I need to add a 'Quantity' column to the StoreProduct table. How would I map this using nHibernate?

An example mapping is provided for the given scenario above, but I'm not sure how I would get the Quantity column to map to a property on the Product class:

```
public class StoreMap : ClassMap<Store>
{
  public StoreMap()
  {
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Name);
    HasMany(x => x.Employee)
      .Inverse()
      .Cascade.All();
    HasManyToMany(x => x.Products)
     .Cascade.All()
     .Table("StoreProduct");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion would be to not use the hasManyToMany mapping and have a separate mapping class for StoreProduct which is a subclass of Product.

New Store Mapping

```
public class StoreMap : ClassMap<Store>
{
  public StoreMap()
  {
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Name);
    HasMany(x => x.Employee)
      .Inverse()
      .Cascade.All();
    HasMany(x => x.Products)
     .Cascade.All();
  }
}
```

**NB changed HasManyToMany to HasMany instead.**

New sub class mapping for Store Product

```
public class StoreProductMap : SubclassMap<StoreProduct>
{
   References(x=>x.Store);

   Map(x=>x.Quantity);
}
```

New StoreProduct entity

```
public class StoreProduct : Product
{
    public virtual Store Store {get;set;}
    public virtual int Quantity {get;set;}
}
```

Hope that helps.