# Hibernate criteria for a junction table - how to create?

Tags: hibernate, join, hibernate-criteria

I have simply 3 tables like:

product
.----------
id
name

category
.----------
id
name

product_category
.----------------------
p_id
c_id

I want to get a list of products where the products have category of id=3.
I am confused about how to write a `hibernate criteria` for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Product.class, "product");
c.createAlias("product.categories", "category");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("category.id", 3));
```

Comment: thanks. for people looking for the same solution note that `setAlias` should be `createAlias`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this implementation

fluent nhibernate implementation
[Fluent nHibernate - How to map a non-key column on a junction table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003025/fluent-nhibernate-how-to-map-a-non-key-column-on-a-junction-table)

nhibernate implementation

http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/08/nhibernate-many-to-many-relationships/

hope this helps

Comment: these are mapping implementations I am after a query implementation with criteria